# is there any difference between upper and lower case bigint datatype?

Tags: sql-server

I noticed a stored procedure with

```
declare @PublicationMinValidVer bigint;  
declare @StartMsgSize BIGINT;
```

Wondering what difference upper and lower case bigint datatype makes and why would one wanna use it.

Comment: Lots of SQL is case-insensitive. They mean the same thing.

Comment: Ah.. ok. thanks Ryan

Comment: Data type names are case-insensitive in later SQL versions. They were case sensitive in old versions with a case-sensitive collation and in certain contexts.